# linking jpeg image in html to php code

Tags: php, html, html-email

im creating a website which includes a button (JPEG image) that will locate ('a ref') a php file. I need the php to be called when the 'email.jpg' button is clicked on but only shows up as pure text in a web browser. any ideas on how to resolve this? any help is much appreciated! thanks

**MAIN HTML SITE CODE**

```
<div id="content-container">

      <p align="center"><a href="video.mp4" class="html5lightbox"  data-width="720" data-height="404"><img src="bg.jpg" width="1023" height="820" id="imgvideo" /></a>          
    <div align="center">
      <table width="1027" height="46" border="0" cellpadding="0px">
          <tr>
            <td><a href="mail.php"><img src="email.png" width="130" height="46" /></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**PHP FILE CODE (mail.php)**

```
 <?php 

/*EMAIL TEMPLATE BEGINS*/ 

$imgSrc   = 'bg.jpg'; 
$imgDesc  = 'test_sell_new/'; 
$imgTitle = 'bg.jpg'; 

$subjectPara1 = 'Now Available'; 
$subjectPara2 = NULL; 
$subjectPara3 = NULL; 
$subjectPara4 = NULL; 
$subjectPara5 = NULL;

$message = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>'.
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"'.
'"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'.
'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'.
'<head>'.
'<title>Available Now</title>'.
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'.
'</head>'.

'<body style="background-color:#ffffff; padding:0; margin:-10px 0 0 0; _margin:0 0 0 0; *margin:0 0 0 0; text-align:center;">'.
'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1024" style="background-color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; padding-top:0px; margin:auto;">'.
    '<tr>'.
        '.<td><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none"><p style="color:#000000; text-align:center; margin:10px 0 0 0; *margin:0 0 0 0; _margin:0 0 0 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">Having trouble viewing this message? Click here.</p></a></td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '<tr>'.
        '<td>'.
            '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="820">'.
                '<tr>'.
                    '<td>'.
                    '<a href="index.html"><img src="bg.jpg" width="1024" height="820" border="0" /></a><br />'.
                    '</td>'.
                '</tr>'.
            '</table>'.
        '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
'</table>'.
'</body>'.

/*EMAIL TEMPLATE ENDS*/ 

$to      = 'test@madeup.com';            
$subject = 'IT WORKS!';   
$from    = 'test@madeup.com';                            

$headers  = "From: " . $from . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "CC: test@example.com\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not really doing anything with your template, send it using mail().

```
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
```

Comment: didnt work as it still opens as a text file and not the email client

Comment: So you want the email template to show up in a email client? And not actually send the mail via PHP?

Comment: yes, it needed to open in an email client but preferably in PHP, if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the start of your php document

`header('Content-type: text/plain');`

That will force the browser to render as text not HTML